# How to use herangehen in a sentence

Tags: meaning, verb, meaning-in-context, verb-usage

Today I lernt this new word ‘herangehen’ which means ‘to approach’. I would like to use it in a sentence.

Is the following usage correct please:

> Ich habe an ihn herangegangen

Also, I would like to know what other synonymous could be, preferably if they are in a sentence

Comment: Correct would be *Ich bin an ihn herangegangen* or depending on the meaning *Ich bin an ihn herangetreten* in a sense like e.g. *I approached my teacher to discuss my excercises.* as opposed to *I approach the man in the bar* meaning getting physically closer to that person by walking over. Maybe [this thread](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46048/the-different-ways-to-approach-somebody-in-german?rq=1) also helps as there are a few examples and their meaning.

Comment: @Mushroomator: Please do not post answers in comments. Please use the *»Your Response«* section to post full Answers. If you feel that what you want to say is not sufficient to be posted as a full answer, please either make it sufficient and post it as a full answer or do not post it at all. See also: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb is related to *gehen* and therefore needs the same auxiliary verb as all verbs of movement. The correct auxiliary verb for these verb is *»sein«,* not *»haben«:*

> Ich bin gelaufen, du bist geschwommen, er ist gekrochen, sie ist geflogen, es ist geschlichen, wir sind gewandert, ihr seid gerobbt, sie sind gehüpft, ...

And therefore:

> Ich bin gegangen, ich bin fortgegangen, ich bin eingegangen, ich bin untergegangen, ...
> Ich **bin** herangegangen.

You can use this verb in the literal meaning, to walk towards something or someone:

> Ich bin an den Veranstalter herangegangen und habe ihn auf das Problem aufmerksam gemacht.
> I approached the organizer and made him aware of the problem.

But this usage is rare. More often you use this verb in a figurative meaning:

> Nachdem ich gestern gescheitert bin, bin ich heute mit neuen Ideen an das Problem herangegangen.
> After failing yesterday, I approached the problem today with new ideas.

You do not approach the thing or person locally, but mentaly.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought with "herangehen" is to approach a problem or a situation, not a person.

For approaching a person for help I would use "Ich bin an ihn herangetreten" or "Ich habe ihn um Hilfe gebeten".

When talking about walking to someone, I would use "Ich bin zu ihm hin gegangen".